# Помощь в чате php

Tags: php

Код chat.php:

```
<script>

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#form").onsubmit(function (event) {
        var message = $("input[name='message']", form).value()
        if (message) { event.preventDefault(); return false; }
        return true;
    });
    $("#form input[name='message']").bind(
        'change keydown keypress',
        function(event) {
            var text = $(this).value().replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
            $("#form input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", text == "");
        }
    );
});
 </script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="850" height="400"></iframe>
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target='chatWindow' > 
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
  $message = $_POST['message'];

}

$db = mysql_connect("", "", "");
mysql_select_db("", $db);
if (trim($message) != "") {
  $time = time();
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,username,time) VALUES 
('$message','{$_SESSION['username']}','$time')");
}

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<br>";
   echo "[".date(' H:i ',$row['time'])."]".$row['username']."  : ".$row['message'];

  }

?>
```

Эти коды только выводят сообщения. Как сделать, чтобы сообщения вводились?

Comment: Не могу ничем помочь, потому что нужен доступ к базе данных - а на лету смотреть код - я не шарю. Возможно, сделай также как ты вывел их ( сообщения ) это же просто ! ИМХО

Comment: можете сказать адрес странички в вк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть форма, которую нужно заполнить. И должно заработать.

```
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target='chatWindow' >
  <input type='text' name='message'>
  <input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</from>
```

Comment: @YuriyProkopets  `if (trim($message) != "") {
  $time = time();
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,username,time) VALUES 
('$message','{$_SESSION['username']}','$time')");
}` он у него есть в php файле

Comment: не было только формы для отправки.

Comment: @ИгорьВасильев отметь мой ответ - галочкой))

Comment: Вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы при отправки сообщения выкладывалось имя пользователя? Авторизация есть

Comment: @ИгорьВасильев куда выкладывалось?

Comment: уже не надо. Как сделать, чтобы показывало московское время? А то сейчас 8:20, выложил сообщение в чате, а там 1:20

Comment: @ИгорьВасильев `php.ini` ищите `date.timezone` устанавливаете значение `Europe/Moscow`

Comment: и можно последний вопрос? Как сделать так, чтобы показывало с последнего сообщения до первого?

Comment: @ИгорьВасильев при выборке из базы используйте сортировку `ORDER BY '<collumn>'`. Почитайте подробнее в интернете.